# Opening a function from another folder/file in python

Tags: python, function, import

so I have a coded a simple function in python and called it `Lag()`. The folder I am saving the python script at is `C:\Users\yo4226ka\Work Folders\Desktop\...\Code` and I call the file `2.5`. I am trying to do something like this:

`from 2.5 import Lag`

I am not quite sure how I could use the folder location to import the function I coded in another script. Any help is appreciated :)!

Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the code as a package and import it later on and use it like regular python packages. This might help you: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-package

Answer (score -1):

did your main script file and 2.5 file exist same folder?
if its condition is true, it is simple.
you just write code below.

```
from Lag import 2.5
```

Comment: This is not correct. The filename is 2.5 and the function name is Lag.